# How can I set up nodejs and expressjs to render many html files that use angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

I'm using:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

to set the static folder for a MEAN application. I need to have several html files that use angularjs(not angular2). The problem I get from this setup is that it only works if the name of the html file is index.

I also tried:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

after installing ejs, where in the views folder I had all the html files. But this didn't work for angular.

How can I set up nodejs and expressjs to render many html files that use angularjs?

Answer (score 0):

use this for  accessing static files like you mentioned
`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));`
and you can add the angular files in to index.html. keep angular related file in the public folder and put it in the index.html when you using it.whether its a controller or service or a directive